# Multiple regex or conditions using groups

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to match several different filename syntaxs with one regex. In other words I am trying to match filename string with the same characters in different orders. The problem is I don't know how to string together "OR" | cases when it comes to groups.

Group syntax:

- Product names constitute any letter any number with optional "-", "_" or spaces in between characters. "-", "_" or spaces are never at the beginning or end of Product name.
- PAF or PA always have a leading "-" followed by a trailing "-" and then a number.
- Revision codes constitute "FG", "RD", "X", "A", or "\d+" all except last followed directly but a number.
- Sheet number is lower or upper cases (hence the re.IGNORECASE) preceded by a "-" a space or nothing, then the word "sheet" followed by "-" space or nothing and then a number.

The filenames follow these patterns:

- (Product Name)-(PAF/PA-#) (Sheet #)-(Revision)
- (\w(?:\w*(?:-|\s|_)?\w+)*)(-PA(?:F|)-\d+)(?:(?:\s|-)sheet(?:\s|-)\d+)(-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)
- (Product Name)-(PAF/PA-#)-(Revision) (Sheet #)
- (\w(?:\w*(?:-|\s|_)?\w+)*)(-PA(?:F|)-\d+)(?:(?:\s|-)sheet(?:\s|-)\d+)(-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)
- (Product Name)-(PAF/PA-#)-(Revision)
- (\w(?:\w*(?:-|\s|_)?\w+)*)(-PA(?:F|)-\d+)(-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)
- (Product Name)-(Revision) (Sheet #)
- (\w(?:\w*(?:-|\s|_)?\w+)*)(-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)(?:(?:\s|-)sheet(?:\s|-)\d+)
- (Product Name)-(Revision)
- (\w(?:\w*(?:-|\s|_)?\w+)*)(-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)

PAF PA are product type denotations, Sheet # is useless info, and FG#, RD#, X#, A#, or # are all product revisions. I need product name, denotation, and revision all to be in their own group.

```py
^(\w(?:\w*(?:-|\s|_)?\w+)*)
(?:
(-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)|
(-PA(?:F|)-\d+)(-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)|
(-PA(?:F|)-\d+)(?:(?:\s|-)sheet(?:\s|-)\d+)|
(-PA(?:F|)-\d+)(?:(?:\s|-)sheet(?:\s|-)\d+)(-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)
)
(?:.*)?$
```

I've tried the above regex but it doesn't work correctly. First it returns too many groups, I would only like 3.

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'''^(\w(?:\w*(?:-|\s|_)?\w+)*)        # match any alphanumeric and dashes without leading or trailing dashes
                         (-PA(?:F|)-\d+)                    # match '-PAF-<number>' or '-PA-<number>'
                         (?:(?:\s|-|)?sheet(?:\s|-|)?\d+)?  # match '?sheet?<number>' where ? can be <space> or '-'
                         (-(?:FG|RD|X|A|)\d+)?              # match '-FG<number>', '-RD<number>', '-X<number>', '-A<number>' or <number>
                         (?:.*)?$''', flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE)
```

The aforementioned strings should match with the regex.

Comment: Can you improve your question please? A clear example with input and expected output will greatly help. thanks

Comment: *Offtopic: Creating such as regular expressions makes code almost unreadable and creates big problems in future support. If you can replace this with list of simple regular expressions and check input to match each of them - do it. It'll definitely save lot of time in future.*

Comment: @abc Sure I can do that. It's the first time I've asked a question on Stack so i'm not too great at asking questions in a way that's easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT after new examples**

To avoid over complicating the regex pattern (which is quite enough already), I would get rid of the "sheet" part first.

So first, remove the "sheet #" pattern from filename before applying the match instruction.

This will reduce your cases to these patterns only:

- (Product Name)-(PAF/PA-#)-(Revision)
- (Product Name)-(Revision)

Then apply the regex to split in three groups.
For the revision group I used (?!...) a negative lookahead assertion to handle cases like this: "2400PSUA-8-PA-1-X0"

Here's the revised code:

```
import re

string = """10G-HUB-PAF-1 Sheet 1-FG0
HUB-DISP-SPCR-RD0
HUB-MAIN-PA-1-FG0
2400ODU-PA-1-X0 Sheet 1
2400PSUA-8-PA-1-Sheet1-X0
2405OE-PAF-1-FG0
2400PSUA-8-PA-1-Sheet1-X0
XXXX-XXX-123-PAF-1-FG0 Sheet 1
"""

regex = r'(?# product name )(.*?)' + \
        r'(?# PA|PAF       )(?:(?:-)(?:(PAF-\d|PA-\d).*))?' + \
        r'(?# Revision     )(?:-)((?:\d)(?!.*(?:FG|RD|X|A\d))|(?:(?:FG|RD|X|A)\d))'

pattern = re.compile(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE)

for s in string.splitlines():
    print('String %s' % s)
    # Remove 'Sheet#' or 'Sheet #' or '-Sheet #' or '-Sheet#'
    s=re.sub(r'-?sheet\s?\d','',s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print('Purged string: %s' % s)
    f=pattern.match(s)
    print('group1: %s' % f.group(1))
    print('group2: %s' % f.group(2))
    print('group3: %s\n' % f.group(3))
```

With some output:

```
String 10G-HUB-PAF-1 Sheet 1-FG0
Purged string: 10G-HUB-PAF-1 -FG0
group1: 10G-HUB
group2: PAF-1
group3: FG0

String HUB-DISP-SPCR-RD0
Purged string: HUB-DISP-SPCR-RD0
group1: HUB-DISP-SPCR
group2: None
group3: RD0

...omitted output ...

String 2400PSUA-8-PA-1-Sheet1-X0
Purged string: 2400PSUA-8-PA-1-X0
group1: 2400PSUA-8
group2: PA-1
group3: X0

String XXXX-XXX-123-PAF-1-FG0 Sheet 1
Purged string: XXXX-XXX-123-PAF-1-FG0 
group1: XXXX-XXX-123
group2: PAF-1
group3: FG0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That said it doesn't match the last group correctly if the revision is just a lone number. For example "XXXXXX-PA-1-1" will fail to match. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I've updated it, so give it a look over.

Comment: @DBFS I changed the regular expression a little. I hope it's what you need now.

Comment: Your updated regex won't match if product takes a format such as "XXXX-XXX-123-PAF-1-FG0 Sheet 1" correctly. Output: ('XXXX-XXX', None, '1') Expected: ('XXXX-XXX-123', 'PAF-1', ''FG0'). Maybe i should have a pattern for each of the different filename formats and then try each one?

Comment: It may be a solution to test, but since more pattern would output a result for the same product, how would you choose which one is the correct one?

Comment: if you can supply some more example of "difficult cases" (as the one xxx-xxx-123-PAF..etc.) it may help untangle the regular expression and force it to do what you need

Comment: I see what you mean with the list. I've added a list of examples to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

After practicing a lot with regex, and with the help from GDN i found the solution:

```
(.*?)(?:(?:\s|_|-|\s?-\s|\s-\s?)(?=(?:PAF-|PA-|FG|RD|X|A)\d+))((?:PAF|PA)-\d+)?(?:\s|_|-|\s?-\s|\s-\s?)?(?:.*?)?((?:FG|RD|X|A)\d+)
```

```py
import re


def input_loop(pattern, doc_type):
    while True:
        filename = raw_input('Enter {}, Enter "x" to Close: '.format(doc_type))
        if filename == 'x':
            break
        matches = pattern.match(filename)
        if matches:
            groups = matches.groups()
            print groups
        else:
            print '''Couldn't match string: "{}"'''.format(filename)

pattern = re.compile(r'''
  (.*?)(?# Match product name)
  (?:(?:\s|_|-|\s?-\s|\s-\s?)(?=(?:PAF-|PA-|FG|RD|X|A)\d+))(?# Match spacer after product name)
  ((?:PAF|PA)-\d+)?(?# Match optional PAF-# or PA-#)
  (?:\s|_|-|\s?-\s|\s-\s?)?(?# Match spacer after product type name)
  (?:.*?)?(?# Match useless data)
  ((?:FG|RD|X|A)\d+)''', flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE)
input_loop(pattern, 'Assembly Drawings')
```